# Construir aplicación usando un archivo application.properties fuera del war

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, weblogic

Estoy intentado generar el war de una aplicación desarrollada con *Spring Boot*, para desplegarla en *weblogic*, sin embargo es necesario que el archivo de configuración, `application.properties`, se encuentre fuera del WAR para posteriores modificaciones, sin embargo no sé cómo desplegarlo, ya que si lo retiro del proyecto como tal, para ponerlo en el path del servidor, no me permite realizar el mvn package.

Estoy llamando el archivo de la siguiente forma:

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ParameterApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
        SpringApplication.run(ParameterApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(ParameterApplication.class);
    }

}
```

El error, es apenas obvio, ya que no encuentra el archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. ¿Podrías poner el error que te arroja el maven package?

Comment: Lo agregué a la publicación c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que no te esta permitiendo generar el WAR es la ejecución de los tests.

Esto por que al ejecutarlos el programa esta buscando el application.properties hay dos formas de evitar este problema sin incluir el application.properties en el WAR final.

**1. Compilar saltando los tests**

Compilar saltando los test (yo no lo haría por que imagino que tus test si te son importantes). Para poder hacer esto puedes ejecutar la compilación por linea de comando:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

O si solo ejecutas el package.

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

**2.Cambiando de lugar el archivo application.properties**

Imagino que tu archivo application.properties esta en:

```
src/main/resources
```

Si es así puedes pasarlo al directorio:

```
src/test/resources
```

[image: directorios]

Con esto el archivo no se incluirá en el WAR final (por que el código de las pruebas no se incluye) y se utilizará solo durante la ejecución de los test.

Coméntame si con esto resuelves tu problema, de no ser así indícame el fallo que te aparece y amplio mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, es lo que estaba buscando para este caso en específico. Sin embargo en la respuesta de Manu, comento mi error actual.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede establecer dicho archivo properties en el classpath del servidor de aplicaciones weblogic.

Si tienes acceso a la consola de administración, solo tienes que entrar en el servidor donde tienes desplegada tu aplicación, ir a la pestaña inicio servidor (Server Start) y podrás ver el campo Classpath.

Ahi hay que indicar la ruta absoluta donde tienes ubicado tu archivo properties. Es decir, si es un linux podría ser /properties/file32.properties.

Esto tiene una pega y es que evitas redesplegar la aplicación cada vez que quieres cambiar el properties. Pero es necesario reiniciar el servidor de aplicaciones para que tome los cambios de dicho properties al tenerlo en el classpath.

Un saludo.

Comment: Lo he hecho de esta forma, y toma el archivo que se encuentra en el classpath, sin embargo después de generar el war, es necesario generar de nuevo el war para que tome los cambios, alguna idea.